# Hibernate field multiple alias

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, postgresql

I am having an entity, which has collections field (params). There can be many params. I want to make unique join for each unique param. i.e. `p1.id = ? AND p2.id = ? AND p3.id = ?` etc.

In Hibernate, when I try to create alias for the same field, it throws exception with message about duplicate alias.

How can I achieve multiple joins for the field?

I am using spring framework, hibernate and postgresql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the code with the query, and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Solved the problem. In this link "https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=943274" at the bottom said: "There is a deep limitation in OuterJoinLoader that prevents the same association being joined twice." which was important for me to know. So i decided to solve the problem with HQL not with Criteria API.

Comment: if you had at least mentioned in your question that you were using the Criteria API, or if you had shown your code, I could have told you that immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using the Criteria API.

If you check the source code of Hibernate you can find the problem here:

```
CriteriaQueryTranslator#createAssociationPathCriteriaMap()

private void createAssociationPathCriteriaMap() {
        Iterator iter = rootCriteria.iterateSubcriteria();
        while ( iter.hasNext() ) {
            CriteriaImpl.Subcriteria crit = ( CriteriaImpl.Subcriteria ) iter.next();
            String wholeAssociationPath = getWholeAssociationPath( crit );
            Object old = associationPathCriteriaMap.put( wholeAssociationPath, crit );
            if ( old != null ) {
                throw new QueryException( "duplicate association path: " + wholeAssociationPath );
            }
            int joinType = crit.getJoinType();
            old = associationPathJoinTypesMap.put( wholeAssociationPath, new Integer( joinType ) );
            if ( old != null ) {
                // TODO : not so sure this is needed...
                throw new QueryException( "duplicate association path: " + wholeAssociationPath );
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using Hibernate 3.3.2.

What happens internally is that When you are adding `Criteria`s to your root `Criteria` Hibernate creates `SubCriteria`s and later fills a `Map` (check the code below) with all the paths you are trying to use and if it finds a duplication it will throw an exception.

So for example if you are trying to join: `entity0.entity1` and later you try to join that again you will get an `Exception`. It won't work even with an alias because Hibernate doesn't care about them here.

You can work around this if you don't join something twice OR you can use HQL/JPQL. You may check out newer versions of Hibernate but I'm not sure if they fixed this quasi-bug.